# Cloudflare, Load balancer, and Yii 2

Tags: yii2, load, load-balancing, cloudflare

So we’re having an issue with using CloudFlare, a load balancer, and Yii 2. It looks like Yii 2 uses an ip-based session persistence, but with CloudFlare + the load balancer, it keeps returning different IPs so users don’t stay logged in. Is there any work around to this or has anyone seen this issue and fixed it?

Comment: You are providing too little information about environment to guess the issue reason. E.g. did you set `sticky` connection on the balancer? Does your app use subdomains? Are cookies enabled? Yii does not use IP based session.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cloudflare Load Balancer, you can enable [Session Affinity](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001771451-Load-Balancing-Session-Affinity) which is a cookie-based persistence.

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like Yii 2 uses an ip-based session persistence

I suggest, you look into that once more. I'm 99.9% sure that yii2 does not do that. Otherwise using yii2 sites on mobile would be a PITA. Phones are always changing IPs because of switching WIFI and getting new data connections.